# UV Mapping object with too many vertices

Tags: uv

I am following the pluralsight course on modeling and UV mapping a drone. At the section where he is unwrapping objects, he has significantly less vertices than my same object after smoothing everything. If anyone has taken the course or knows a faster more accurate way to mark seams, any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: To get better help please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand the issue.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Maybe you applied some modifier that he didnt? For seam selection you can use shortest path select between two vertices while holding ctrl...

Comment: Thank you, I will probably go back and see if there is something I did wrong or missed but thank you for the suggestion i'll give it a shot.